# Can I make a domain name point to a local IP address?

Tags: routes, ip

What I want to do is type a name in a browser (something like mylocalists.com) and have it translate to a local address like 192.168.1.100.  The reason for this is to call a page on a local Apache server at home and at work the same name would bring up my site from a server on that network with the same IP address.  The sites would differ (locally pertinent content) depending where I am but have the same name and address.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an entry to your local hosts file (/etc/hosts, if you are on a mac or linux box):

```
192.168.1.100   mylocalists.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing your /etc/hosts file is an option if you only have one client computer. However if you want this to work in every computer or device in your local network you should configure a DNS server.

https://www.redhat.com/magazine/025nov06/features/dns/